# Объединение профилей StackExchange

Tags: поддержка, stackexchange

У меня есть два профиля в **StackExchange**: один профиль классический, а второй давным-давно создал через **Google**. Есть ли возможность их как-нибудь объединить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Перейдите по ссылке https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact
2. Выберите «Мне необходимо объединить учётные записи», заполните остальные поля.
3. Отправьте и ждите ответа от сотрудников Stack Overflow.

Comment: Как быть в случае обнаружения двух учёток стороннего пользователя?