# Регистрация на stackoverflow.com с помощью Google аккаунта

Tags: поддержка, регистрация

Подскажите (желательно подробно с указанием ссылок на скриншотах), как зарегистрироваться на stackoverflow.com через аккаунт google.

Comment: Вы ведь уже зарегистрированный пользователь?

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2454/262779

Answer (score 2):

Как ни странно, но выбрать эту опцию после нажатия кнопки регистрации[image: регичтрация]

Comment: А до этого в какие элементы щелкать? Я рассчитывал на полный ответ.

Comment: Если вы хотите привязать существующий аккаунт, тогда Профиль -> Править -> Доступ